How to find the source code of the Algorithm for random number generation in NumPy?
like in the title, I'm searching for the exact location of source code for e.g. numpy.random.normal. I would like to know for this and some other distributions whether the random numbers are created with Inverse Transformation or another method.
Tank's in advance
I tried to search in distributions.c.

did you try the official docs?  https://numpy.org/

and here:  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy-random-normal

I think the normal numbers are calculated either here using the polar form of Box-Muller, or here, using a Ziggurat algorithm. I can't tell which is actually used.

Found a changelog which clarifies things: Box-Muller is used before 1.17.0. In 1.17.0, it was changed to Ziggurat. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e59c074842e3f73483afa5ddef031e856b9fd313/doc/source/reference/random/new-or-different.rst#whats-new-or-different
